# What is the most secure way to retrieve the system Drive

Tags: c#, .net, windows, environment-variables, system-administration

I know that the following should work:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine)
```

My problem with this call is that if for some reason someone decided to remove the "windir" Env Var , this won't work.

Is there an even more secure way to get the System drive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing i actually maybe misunderstand is that you want the System Drive, but by using "windir" you'll get the windows folder. So if you need a *secure way* to get the windows folder, you should use the good old API function GetWindowsDirectory.

Here is the function prepared for C# usage. ;-)

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern uint GetWindowsDirectory(StringBuilder lpBuffer, uint uSize);

    private string WindowsDirectory()
    {
        uint size = 0;
        size = GetWindowsDirectory(null, size);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder((int)size);
        GetWindowsDirectory(sb, size);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

So if you really need the drive on which windows is running, you could afterwards call

```
System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(WindowsDirectory());
```

Comment: @Richard: That's right, but instead of just pointing to the concrete direction i added a sample, on how the function can be used.

Answer (score 31):

```
string windir = Environment.SystemDirectory; // C:\windows\system32
string windrive = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory); // C:\
```

Note: This property internally uses the GetSystemDirectory() Win32 API. It doesn't rely on environment variables.

Answer (score 9):

This one returns the path to the system directory (system32).

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System)
```

You may be able to use that, then you don't need to rely on environment variables.

Comment: It's worth noting that GetFolderPath elates your environment variable fears since it uses SHGetFolderPath internally.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [GetWindowsDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724454(VS.85,loband).aspx) API to retrieve the windows directory.

Answer (score 1):

Never read environment variables (any script or user can change them !)
The **official** method (MS internal, used by Explorer) is a Win32 api FAQ for decades (see Google groups, Win32, System api)

Answer (score 0):

Theres an environment variable called `SystemDrive`

```
C:\>SET SystemDrive
SystemDrive=C:
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that method suffers from the same problem as the original WinDir environment variable - a user can arbitrarily change or remove it from their environment.