# Get root path for operating system

Tags: rust, path, filesystems

I would like to get the root specifier in Rust that will work on all computers from a. So, for example, on Linux I would expect `/` to be returned, on Windows I would expect `C;`. Is there any way to do this is a system independent way with Rust?

Comment: there is no concept of root in windows, all drive have their root and so this don't make sense for windows

Comment: And while the Windows OS is _typically_ found on drive `C:`, there's afaik no guarantee that it _always_ is.

Comment: That's why I wanted to find a function in Rust that reliably delivers the correct root path for all operating systems, instead of hard-coding my self an if else depending on os name

Comment: @Stargateur here i want the root name of the partition that the operating system is running on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows, get the location of the system directory using [`GetSystemDirectorW`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/System/SystemInformation/fn.GetSystemDirectoryW.html), and then get the drive that it's on.

See also [What is the most secure way to retrieve the system Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910004/what-is-the-most-secure-way-to-retrieve-the-system-drive)

For Unix-likes, the root directory is always `/`.